# Sequential deletes on S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to delete two files, "A" and "B" from an S3 bucket such that the bucket will never be in a state where A is there but not B. So I accept A and B being there or only B. (A gets deleted "before-or-equally" to B).

S3 has a multi-object delete, but it does not say anything about the deletes being atomic (so it is not?). But does anyone know if we are guaranteed that two deletes after each other will effect the bucket in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

Deletes on S3 are eventually consistent. There is no way to guarantee the order.